# javascript calculation sometimes not happening

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In the following code snippet:

```
var scr_h = $(document).height();
var scr_w = $(document).width();
var logo = {                                                             
    width   :   (scr_w*.25),                                              
    img     :   document.createElement('img'),                           
    src     :   'images/static/mk_vc.png'                                
};  
$(logo.img).attr('src', logo.src);                                       
$('#logo').append(logo.img);                                             
$('#logo').css({                                                         
    'margin-top'    :   scr_h*.15+'px',                                       
    'width'         :   logo.width+'px',
    'left'          :   (scr_w/2)-(logo.width/2)+'px' //this doesn't always work...
}); 
alert($('#logo').css('left'));
```

Sometimes the alert comes back with "auto" instead of the correct number. It usually happens if the page is refreshed (though a ctrl+refresh will usually fix the issue). I tried rendering the page via php and attaching a `?randomnumber=$randomnumber` parameter to the JavaScript call, but it didn't help, which means it's not a caching issue of some sort.

It also seems to happen in all browsers. My client has a Mac, and has tried with Chrome and Safari, and I have Linux and have tried it in Chrome and Firefox.

Any thoughts at all? The rest of the JavaScript functions fine, regardless as to whether that particular line renders properly. The `margin-top` and `width` css also always functions. It appears to be only the `left` that gives issues.

I tried changing the order to render "left" first, but that also did not help, though the other two attributes were still just fine.

The full script can be seen at http://meenakhalili.turnleftllc.com/scripts/js/dev/mk.js, with the site at meenakhalili.turnleftllc.com. Try refreshing a few times. You'll see the problem.

Comment: this happens in all browsers?

Comment: Sorry, yes. Well, at least in chrome, firefox, and safari. I do not have IE. Edited the question to include that information

Comment: Just an FYI: `$(document).ready(function() {main();});` can be written as `$(document).ready( main );` or even better `jQuery( main );`

Comment: Try to execute the code in the onload event of the image

Comment: Good thought. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Do you realize that `.left` doesn't do anything unless `position` is set to something like `relative` or `absolute`.

Comment: Also, I hate seeing code like this: `$(logo.img).attr('src', logo.src);` when `logo.img.src = logo.src` is way more efficient.  Use jQuery ONLY when it's a more efficient way of doing things.  One property assignment is way more efficient than multiple functions calls.

Comment: @chcrist - That appears to have fixed it! I would buy you a six pack if you lived near me. If you put that in answer form  I'll give you the cred!

Comment: `.css("left")` will actually call `getComputedStyle` (or IE equivalent when in IE) and it will return `"auto"` when the position is `"static"` (which is default position). So is `"#logo"` position absolute, relative or fixed?

Comment: jfriend -- position *is* absolute.

Comment: `alert( $('#logo').css('left') + " " + $('#logo').css('position') )` what does that alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chchrist answered this question last night in the comments. Setting the calculation to occur after the onload event of the image fixed the problem.

I'm posting this for now, but would love to give credit where it's due!

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on when the code executes with respect to the page being rendered, which is indeterminate if the code is wrapped in $(function(){...}) or similar.

You could try measuring the window rather than the document:

```
var scr_h = $(window).height();
var scr_w = $(window).width();
```